# Где хранятся изображения django simple captcha?

Tags: django

При просмотре кода страницы видно, что адрес изображения выглядит как-то так: http://127.0.0.1:8000/captcha/image/5d1c83a9a4a2b063abd792bc3035a0ee64ac0ddf/

Однако по адресу директории проекта нет никакой папки captcha, так откуда страница подгружает изображение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изображение генерируется и хранится в оперативной памяти перед тем как будет отдано на клиент. В [исходном коде](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/blob/fddf2fefd26540b432ae43c6971134e4b192c875/captcha/views.py#L35) для генерации используется библиотека Pillow. [Данные сохраняются в io.BytesIO](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/blob/fddf2fefd26540b432ae43c6971134e4b192c875/captcha/views.py#L130) в случае создания изображения и отправки на клиент.

Comment: Тогда почему изображение имеет путь с директориями и название файла?

Comment: @MaGrAs в HTTP запросе URL не имеет связи с директориями или файлами, он просто указывает, какой метод сервера должен быть вызван. Условно на сервере будет метод `def captcha(request, type, key)` и он будет вызван.

Comment: В данном случае для капчи будет вызван метод `captcha`. Далее в переменной `type` будет передан тип капчи `image` - помимо изображения (def captcha_image) можно получить аудио капчу (def captcha_audio). В конце параметром пути передается ключ для генерации изображения в переменной `key`: `random.seed(key)` в параметр рандома. Никакой связи с физическими директориями нет.

Comment: Случаи для статических файлов и изображений из директорий настраиваются отдельно на сервере и тогда действительно это будут директории с названием. Но в данном случае это не так. По крайней мере исходный код генерирует изображения в памяти и отдает их сразу массивом байт клиенту.